# Angular child component not firing change event on list

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui

I have got one parent component that makes an ajax call and gets the data from the backend for grid. For rendering grid data I have created one child component where I am passing the list as an in binding but whenever I am changing list in my parent component the child component never fires onchange event. My code is below. One more thing I am using these parent and child components under another component which is using shitty kendo tabstrip. I am using tabstrip for official reason but I just hate all the kendo controls at the moment they are designed for jquery but getting sold with label of angular comaptible

Parent component

```
<div layout="column">
    <md-content>
        <div layout="row">
            <member-mvlicense-grid member-id="vm.memberId"></member-mvlicense-grid>
        </div>
    </md-content>
</div>
```

My Child component

```
<md-content>
    <div kendo-grid="vm.grid" options="vm.gridOption" ng-style="{'height':vm.gridHeight}"
         k-on-change="vm.handleChange(data, dataItem, columns)"></div>
</md-content>
```

Parent on change event

```
public $onChanges(onChangesObj: angular.IOnChangesObject): void {
            //this.dataList = new Array<model.member.IMembersMVLicensesResult>();
            if (this.memberId && this.memberId.toString().toLowerCase() != "add") {


this.membersMVLicensesService.getByMemberId(this.memberId).then((response) => {
                this.timeString = new Date().getTime().toString();
                let someValue = response;
                this.dataList = someValue;
                console.log(this.dataList);
            }, (error) => {

            });
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The Kendo Grid change event does not fire when the Grid is populated("on list").

> Fired when the user selects a table row or cell in the grid.

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#events-change

The Grid fires its dataBound event when the grid is populated.
But, it does not seem like there is an angular binding for this event...at least I have not been able to find one.  I've tried k-on-dataBound and k-on-databound.

So, it looks like you will have to bind the dataSource event in your gridOption implementation, i.e.:

```
$scope.gridOption= {
      ...
      dataBound: function() {
        // your handleChange implementation
      },
```

**Edit**
I found the binding...it is

```
k-on-data-bound
```

So you can try that instead of k-on-change.

Comment: I am using it in kendo tabstrip not kendo grid

Comment: From the code provided, your child component is clearly a grid("kendo-grid") and your problem has been stated that the onchange event isn't firing when you list it.  You also do not have a tabstrip anywhere is your code,  So, you will have to provide a *runnable* example that clearly shows your issue if you expect to receive any help.